# How can I get a JavaScript v8 console for offline usage?

Tags: javascript, console, v8, stdio

I am practicing online programming contest held by codeforces, and I try to play javascript with it. However, I find it very difficult to setup my environment for offline test, they have readline() for input to stdio and print()/write() for output in stdout. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: What you're looking for is [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Comment: ot just Inspect Element on any tab of chrome, even the New Tab

Comment: You can also start Chrome's Developer Tools any time you want, even on an empty page, while offline.

Comment: You most likely want to install `node.js` which is easy to use and comes with a lot of useful builtins for development, if you want a native plain-JS interpreter you're looking for `d8`.

Comment: If you have problems with your setup and want our help, you need to show us that setup. What did you install (how)? What doesn't work?

Comment: I have a working V8 5.7.0 (d8.exe) for Windows 10 64-bits, though Codeforces still use V8 4.8.0 (also d8). Let me know if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

For practising Javascript, you could use any thing from the chrome development console to online editors like JSFiddle. Nodejs allows you to run Javascript (which is used for client side rendering) on a server. What this means is that using node, you could run javascript on your terminal. As for the input , output functions you mentioned, it is easy to require them as node modules or use appropriate Javascript libraries for the same.

Comment: "*online editors like JSFiddle*" - huh? OP is explicitly asking about offline usage.

Comment: Can you name a few browser-js library that can do those?